# How to navigate pageview pages with overwrite back button in AppBar?

Tags: flutter, button, navigation, widget, flutter-pageview

I have a pageview view and it works with sliding. But how do I integrate this back button as leading: Icon(backbutton), when navigating between forms in the pageview? Thanks

screen1.dart

```
import 'package:app/src/features/examples/components/body.dart';

class OnboardingExampleFlowPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = "/onboarding_example_flow";

  const OnboardingExampleFlowPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 1,
        backgroundColor: AppColors.monochromeWhite,
        title: Text(context.l10n.buttonBack),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      body: const Body(),
    );
  }
}
```

Body has pageview:

body.dart

```
class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  int currentPage = 0;
  final PageController controller = PageController();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> formPages = <Widget>[
      ExampleContent01(controller: controller),
      ExampleContent02(controller: controller),
      ExampleContent03(controller: controller),
      ExampleContent04(controller: controller),
    ];
    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 6),
            AppStepper(
              currentPage: currentPage,
              length: formPages.length,
              noSkip: true,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20),
                ),
                child: PageView(
                  controller: controller,
                  onPageChanged: (value) => setState(() => currentPage = value),
                  children: formPages,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

These forms: There are contents in ExampleScreens, but I did not add their code because there are AppBar and Pageview in the code I added.

here is view: [image] want to be able to go back inside pageview.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `controller` up, to the parent widget, so it's possible to navigate the pages with it.

Check out the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=daab88abec6d122f7acffbc439b2cb13).

[image]

The code is going to be like the following:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const OnboardingExampleFlowPage(),
      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class OnboardingExampleFlowPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = "/onboarding_example_flow";

  const OnboardingExampleFlowPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OnboardingExampleFlowPage> createState() =>
      _OnboardingExampleFlowPageState();
}

class _OnboardingExampleFlowPageState extends State<OnboardingExampleFlowPage> {
  final PageController controller = PageController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 1,
        title: const Text('Back'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            controller.previousPage(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
              curve: Curves.easeOut,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Body(controller: controller),
    );
  }
}

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  const Body({super.key, required this.controller});

  final PageController controller;

  @override
  State<Body> createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  int currentPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const List<Widget> formPages = [
      Center(child: Text('Page 1')),
      Center(child: Text('Page 2')),
      Center(child: Text('Page 3')),
      Center(child: Text('Page 4')),
    ];
    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 6),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: PageView(
                  controller: widget.controller,
                  onPageChanged: (value) => setState(() => currentPage = value),
                  children: formPages,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Enables scrolling with mouse dragging
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for answer I got an error like this :    PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it.
Failed assertion: line 173 pos 7: 'positions.isNotEmpty'   I have checked internet and added the body this code but this is not working :   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentPage = 0;
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPage = controller.page!.toInt();
      });
    });
  }
 thanks!

Comment: It looks like the controller is being accessed before the `PageView` even exists. The error should be somewhere else. Where you're trying to access the `controller`? Please update the code with the real use case

Comment: thank you so much i fixed it, clicked useful answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Dont have **body** widget in separate file

Put it in the **_OnboardingExampleFlowPageState** instead.

And it is the **_OnboardingExampleFlowPageState** that should have **controller** and
**currentIndex** variables.

So on **leading button click** you'll do something like this:

```
  onPressed: () {
                        if (currentPage > 0) {
                          controller.previousPage(
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                            curve: Curves.easeOut,
                          );
                          setState(() {
                            currentPage--;
                          });
                        }
                      },
```